# Output XML code with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

Consider the following script for outputting some XML code:

```
    var xmlAsString = '<?xml version="1.0"?><person><name gender="male"></name></person>';

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".generator").click(function(){
            alert(xmlAsString);
            $("#container").append("<div id='contXML'>"+xmlAsString+"</div>")
    });
    });
```

The alert outputs everything as I want but nothing shows later. If I put some random string variable (without the < > chars everything works fine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you have to html encode your xml otherwise the browser tries to parse it. I use this simple function.

```
var xmlAsString = '<?xml version="1.0"?><person><name gender="male"></name></person>';
function htmlEncode(value){
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".generator").click(function() {
        alert(xmlAsString);
        $("#container").append("<div id='contXML'>" + htmlEncode(xmlAsString) + "</div>")
    });
});
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/DqDEU/